Didn't move my Solana during the ieo before website shut down I lost access to my purchase
About 2 years ago. I don't know there was an IEO and I was invited. I took $1,500 money US dollars and bought Solana and I used all of it to buy Solana and I wasn't aware that the website was going to close down when it did and I never moved my crypto so I lost control of it and I no longer know how to access it. Is there anybody that can tell me how to retrieve this money? Because it's quite a bit now. It's somewhere close to the half a million please. I've tried to ask here before and maybe I asked the wrong question. I do have screenshots but I don't want to give those out yet. Did I lose it or can I still access it? Please let me know
